# Is there a Mayan Hieroglyph font or complete icon set somewhere online for free?

Tags: fonts, reference-request

I am looking for the icons/glyphs from [here](http://www.famsi.org/research/pitts/MayaGlyphsBook1Sect1.pdf):

[image]

The only thing I could find was this [Mayan Hieroglyph font](https://www.dafont.com/mayan-glyphs.font), but having looked at it briefly it looks like it only supports letters.

[image]

I haven't learned much about the mayan hieroglyphs yet, just wondering if anything exists out there that includes all of them.

Comment: Its not possible to have a full set of Mayan hieroglyphs due to the way they are written. You would need to draw them for each occasion. But you can have a comprehensive suite yes.